# How to fix hamburger menu

Tags: jquery, css, hamburger-menu

My hamburger icon is broken on Chrome developer tools -> mobile emulator. The 3 lines aren't aligned with the center, however, on my iPhone everything looks great.
Here's the link - http://merehead.com/
Can I fix it somehow through CSS, either make only JS patch to detect user device and make the necessary position to it?

I've attached a screenshot, where you can see 'left:-4px' - to center icon on mobile. I suppose the reason is on iphone, and not Chrome?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please add relevant information to your question and [don't post just a link to your project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: please add  in detail your code with

Answer (score -1):

i thinks it should be replace class. right way ?

```
.hamburger-box {
    width: 30px;
    height: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```